# How to set point of rotation in pyqt Qtransformed?

Tags: pyqt5, qpixmap

I am trying to rotate Qpixmap with Qtransformed, it seems the point of rotation is center of pixmap by default, how can i define custom point for example top mid of pixmap?

def rotate_pixmap(self):

```
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")
    self.rotation += 1
    transform = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.rotation)
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(transform, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed): "the pixmap produced is the smallest pixmap that contains all the transformed points of the original pixmap." This means that rotating around another point wouldn't change anything, as the whole image would still appear, which is what gives you the effect that it's rotated around the center. Can you clarify what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reponse on the query, Actually i am developing a GUI app to drive a robotic arm, GUI uploads an image using Qpixmap for defining robots moving path, there is need to rotate pixmap as per required, i have done the rotation using Qtransform but i need to rotate it from top mid to correctly define the robot path.

Comment: See the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).